# Plugin or extension for google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any plugin or extension for google chrome to reload the web page if the internet disconnects and connects it again? or

Is there any plugin or extension for google chrome to reload the web page if the server connection is down and is up again.

For all than i need plugin/extension to tries to reload in 5 secs interval. This should start reloading only when the server is down/web page is lost/internet connection is down.

Please suggest a plugin/extension or guide me some material to develop this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure,
you can use [Google Chrome Auto-Reload plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ofojbjgaaddibdfpmmjeonahgbacejid)

it has three running modes which you can switch between by clicking the icon appearing at your link's bar right. You will need the third mode, which is the aggressive reload.

When that is on, the page will **try to keep reloading** every XX seconds.
If the internet is disconnected, the page will not display.. But as soon as it appears, it will reload again after the same XX seconds pass.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It sounds good. But when i installed this plugin in chrome, the plugin didnt become active. I cant see the blue color reload button as they mentioned. I cant see plugin logo as well in address bar

Comment: Please help on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Go to Options -> Tools -> Extensions and see if the plugin has any options to play with.. Does it appear there at least?

Comment: Thanks, it is reloading. But as u said when internet connection down, the page will not appear, even the reload icon disappears, and when internet connection is up, i cant see the reload icon in that tab. stil it is disappperaed

Comment: Strange to be honest, I am using it for the same exact reason as you are, and it works. Are there any similar plugins installed that might be in conflict? I use it to follow a support-ticketing by the way, and it loads my pending tickets all day long since like a year now ;)

Comment: can i get your mail id? so that i can attach my screenshot for the issue am facing. please help me on this